# PyQt5 and Qt5.5 : license incompatibility

Tags: licensing, qt5, compatibility, pyqt5

this is my problem:
i wanted to install PyQt5 on my fedora22. I have installed Sip as requested and i have noticed that my qt pre-installed version was the 4. Seeing that the 5 was not available in the repos, i installed it from the site.

But when i manually set the path to the qmake in the python3 configue.py --qmake option to configure PyQt5 he says: "Error: This version of PyQt5 and the commercial version of Qt have incompatible licenses."
how can i solve it???

the site says it has double license, when installing i skipped the qt account login and it was written "opensource" .

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here, reeplace "QLibraryInfo::licensee()" for "Open Source" on the configure.py script.

Comment: i tried but it didn't solve the problem, the error message using the --verbose option was this:

qtdetail.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
qtdetail.cpp:16:12: error: ‘Open’ was not declared in this scope
     out << Open source << '\n';
            ^
qtdetail.mk:596: recipe for target 'qtdetail.o' failed
make: *** [qtdetail.o] Error 1
Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation.

Comment: I wrote "Open source" but same result with "Open Source"

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/ANN-PyQt-v5-5-and-SIP-v4-16-9-Released-td5167102.html) on PyQt mailing list.

Comment: thanks for this very useful comment! i wrote them and they fixed this bug in the latest snapshot.

Comment: @tidus i still get the same problem, are you able to install PyQt5.5?

Comment: Yes, i downloaded Qt5.5 with the offline installer. then PyQt5 (not the download file at the beginning of the page but the snapshot at the end of the page). they've just fixed the license bug and  it worked following the instructions in the PyQt reference guide

Answer (score 1):

You can comment the lines in configure.py (of PyQt) relative to this check.
-> lines 2591 to 2594 for me.

Works for PyQt-gpl-5.5 ; sip-4.16.9
with Qt5.5 open source GPL version installed through the .run file.